# Default picture not working using ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My code is expected to show if my random image is `null`.
But nothing is happens, I tried to change the `undefined` state to `null` as well but it did not have any effect.

```
getImgUrl (image) {
  if (image === null){
    return './noimage.jpeg';
  }
  return 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + image;
}
```

Comment: Try console.log(image) and see what you get, most probably image is not null, as a shorthand/safer way you can do if(!image) { return ...} because it might be an empty string, undefined, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you comparing with `===` here - like explained in:
[Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/4464653)

> The `==` operator will compare for equality *after doing any necessary type conversions*.  The `===` operator will **not** do the conversion, so if two values are not the same type `===` will simply return `false`.

so you may want to compare using typ conversation, using: `if (image == null)`

```
getImgUrl (image) {
  if (image == null){
     return './noimage.jpeg';
  }
  return 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + image;
}
```